# is there an iOS emulator?

Tags: css, mobile, web

I've searched high and low for a simple iOS emulator capable of parsing the meta tag "media=only..." for rendering CSS-based media queries. (I'm not looking for a full on application development program like xCode)
It seems the "emulators" I've tried out are nothing more than pathetic simulations (usually just an iframe) of what the URL might look like as displayed at a mobile device width (480px).

I've heard that xCode works as an emulator but it's a 1.6 GB download and I have to register myself as an app developer with Apple (not really a problem at all but it seems a bit too extravagant for my basic needs - like using a bazooka to kill a fly).

I would like to use Media Queries instead of jQuery for mobile, but it seems this CSS3 tag is not compatible with any browsers. For the time being I'm having to test my work on my actual iPhone. Obviously that's a precise "real-world" rendering of it - which is great, but rather time-consuming (FTP your changes just to see a minimal style change - this isn't PHP, I shouldn't need to do that!)

I'd appreciate some input! 
Thanks guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Xcode is fine. You only have to register if you want to deploy an app to the iDevice. You can download Xcode free from the App Store, and from within the included iOS Simulator you can run Safari and test whatever you want.

Comment: +1 iOS simulator that comes with xcode is what you're looking for. You're on a Mac, right?

Comment: Sure am. I had to download an older version of xCode because I don't run Mountain Lion. I'll let oyu know how it goes. :)

Comment: You need to look in your OS X install disk then. If the version on the App Store doesn't work, then that's your only real alternative.

Answer (score 0):

If your dev machine is on a local network and it has a server running, point safari on your iPhone at it via the IP address, from terminal type:

Ifconfig

To get your ip.

Alternatively you could use xCode - you don't have to register as an app developer as far as I know.

Or use a service like http://www.Browserstack.com

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to install Xcode take a look at [browserstack.com](http://www.browserstack.com)

Comment: Browserstack is nice but there are only 3 resolutions available in the free version. 1280, 1024, 800. Pretty useless for someone wanting to check 480 or less.

Comment: That's true but the last time I used it you could run the ios emulator there to.  According to the docs you still can